# Are the mysql replicas from docker-compose replicated?

Tags: mysql, docker

The following docker-compose.yml snippet for database creates two replicas for mysql.
Does it setup group-replication between the two databases

```
image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    
env_file:
  - ./.env
    
volumes:
  - "/usercode/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
    
deploy:
  replicas: 2
    
networks:
  - app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are independent containers with the same initialization. In mysql you need to setup the replication explicitly. This is because MySQL does not know docker exist.

You can use this page to help you [setup mysql docker replication](https://sesamedisk.com/docker-mysql-master-slave-replication-with-docker/)